# No module named 'opentelemetry' in chromadb

Tags: python, chromadb

I have hosted chroma db in aws using docker it was working fine and there was no changes made in the code no redeployment done, I am getting this error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'opentelemetry'
```